# Invalid Column name 'password'

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button1Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserThomasConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from RegisterFormTable where User_Name='" + TextBox1Username.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    conn.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from RegisterFormTable where User_Name='" + TextBox1Username.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
        string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        password = string.Join("", password.Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        if (password == TextBox2Password.Text)  
        {
            Session["New"] = TextBox1Username.Text;
            Response.Write("Password is correct");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Password is not correct");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Username is not correct");
    }
    conn.Close();

}


string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

This is line code that is error

[image]

Please help. what should I do?

Comment: You should not do two queries to the db. You should do only one query `SELECT Count(*) FROM where User_Name = <<username>> and password = <<password>>`. and if this returns the row then you should log the user in.

Comment: On the side not, 1. You must not store the password as plain text in the database. 2. You must use parameterized queries to protect your application from SQL injections.

Comment: Another note NOT to store plain-text password and to use parameterized queries. These two things are too important to do wrong, **even for learning and proof-of-concept projects.**

Answer (score 2):

```
using BCrypt.Net; // Add this package via NuGet


protected void Button1Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Note the different column name. You'll have to change the table to use a hash instead of a raw password!
    // You also have to change the user creation and password change code to create the hash values instead of saving the raw text
    // THIS IS IMPORTANT!!!
    string SQL = "select passwordHash from RegisterFormTable where User_Name= @UserName";

    using var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserThomasConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    using var com = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);

    // Use the actual column type and length from the database here
    com.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = TextBox1Username.Text;
    conn.Open();
    string hash = com.ExecuteScalar() as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(hash))
    {
        Response.Write("Username is not correct");
    }
    else if (BCrypt.Verify(TextBox2Password.Text, hash))
    {
        Session["New"] = TextBox1Username.Text;
        Response.Write("Password is correct");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Password is not correct");     
    }
}
```